# Illegal mix of collations (utf8mb4_general_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation '='

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

```
 if ($webservice_call && $errno) {
         $dbg = debug_backtrace();
        WebserviceRequest::getInstance()->setError(500, '[SQL Error] ' . $this->getMsgError() . '. From ' . (isset($dbg[3]['class']) ? $dbg[3]['class'] : '') . '->' . $dbg[3]['function'] . '() Query was : ' . $sql, 97);
     } elseif (_PS_DEBUG_SQL_ && $errno && !defined('PS_INSTALLATION_IN_PROGRESS')) {
         if ($sql) {
             throw new PrestaShopDatabaseException($this->getMsgError() . '<br /><br /><pre>' . $sql . '</pre>');
         }

         throw new PrestaShopDatabaseException($this->getMsgError());
     }
```

When I upgrade my work

I was forced to add more databases I get this error

Anyone can help, please!

Comment: This happen when in the sql query there is an equality between two text fields that have different collation. It can be, for example, in the ON clause on a JOIN. To fix that all your fields must share the same collation. Instead, if you want to fix this issue in your query, you can use collate casting, eg. "myfield COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci = myOtherField COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that worked for me (using phpMyAdmin).

1. Log in to phpMyAdmin.
2. Select your database from the list on the left.
3. Click on "Operations" from the top set of tabs.
4. In the Collation box, choose your new collation from the dropdown menu.

> I also checked
> *Change all tables collations
> *Change all tables columns collations